# Am I using std::move() too often?

Tags: c++, c++17, move, move-semantics

I finally feel like I understand move semantics in Modern C++, and it's had a dramatic change on the way I write code. Right now, I'm working on an application that uses dependency injection and I'm incorporating my newfound knowledge of move semantics, but I end up using `std::move()` so much that I'm worried I'm using it incorrectly.

Previously, if I wanted to inject a dependency that I needed a copy of in my object, I'd write my constructor like this:

```
class NeedsCopyOfFoo
{
public:
  NeedsCopyOfFoo(const Foo& foo)
    : m_myFoo{foo} {}
private:
  Foo m_myFoo;
};
```

Now, my classes look like this:

```
class NeedsCopyOfFoo
{
public:
  NeedsCopyOfFoo(Foo foo)
    : m_myFoo{std::move(foo)} {}
private:
  Foo m_myFoo;
};
```

There are classes in my design which take as many as three or four class-type dependencies, and I end up moving them all. Obviously, If the caller of my constructor is not able to invoke the constructor with an rvalue, but also isn't going to use the dependency after constructing a `NeedsCopyOfFoo` object, I also need to use `std::move()` there, to avoid a completely unnecessary copy.

Is this the way that Modern C++ is supposed to look? Does Uncle Bob mention a code smell of "Uses `std::move()` too often"? Am I overreacting because I'm just not used to writing in this new style yet?

Comment: If `Foo` doesn't have a move constructor then this is obsolete (extra copy is made). If it does it is ok.

Comment: I would do `NeedsCopyOfFoo(Foo&& foo) : m_myFoo{std::move(foo)} {}` forcing caller to have required `move` too.

Comment: [tag:rust] has move by default, and you should be explicit about copy :-)

Comment: @Jarod42: Why? Now the caller can't pass you `const` inputs without explicitly copying them. If you're writing Rust, write Rust, but insisting on writing one language as another language is ridiculous.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I mentioned rust, as they might have chosen the correct default (as "new" language). In C++, having/allowing extra implicit copy by default is sad. But, indeed, impact mainly depends how costly it is to copy/move `Foo`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR: If you don't care about having perfect performance then

```
Class(const Foo& foo, const Bar& bar, ...) : m_myFoo{foo}, m_myBar{bar}, ...{...} {}
```

is the constructor for you.  It takes rvalues/lvalues and is going to cost you a copy.  It's about as good as you can get and makes life easy, and there is a lot to be said for having an easy life.

---

For just one variable I would have an overload set like

```
NeedsCopyOfFoo(Foo&& foo) : m_myFoo{std::move(foo)} {}
NeedsCopyOfFoo(const Foo& foo) : m_myFoo{foo} {}
```

This cost at most one copy or one move operation depending on what type of object is passed to the constructor.  This is as perfect as you can get.

Unfortunately this does not scale well.  When you start to add more parameter that you want to handle the same way the overload set grows quadratically.  That's not fun at all as a 4 parameter constructor would need 16 overloads to be perfect.  To combat this we can use a forwarding constructor and limit it with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) so it only takes the types you want.  That would give you a constructor like

```
template<typename T, 
         typename U, 
         std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible_v<T, Foo> &&
                          std::is_convertible_v<U, Bar>, bool> = true>
Class(T&& foo, U&& bar) : 
    m_myFoo{std::forward<T>(foo)}, 
    m_myBar{std::forward<U>(bar)} {}
```

This gives you the best performance, but as you can see it is quite verbose and requires you to know a lot more about C++ to work with.

Comment: These are all good tools to have in your toolbox.  And so is the pass-by-value idiom demonstrated in the question.  The trick is picking the right tool at the right time. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly detailed answer! In applications where performance is critical, would you tend to lean towards this forwarding constructor for new classes, despite its verbosity? Also, I'm not very familiar with SFINAE, but how would you say this impacts the readability of your code? Or not at all?

Comment: @EDTwardy SFINAE in my experience does impact the readability.  If you're used to templates it's no so bad but if you are not it can start to look like gibberish.  As far as performance impact, I would test it.  The compiler can do a lot of optimizations and your little extra object creation cost might not even matter.  I would start with my first suggestion, or using pass by value and move, profile, and see if it even matters.  My rule of thumb is write the code naturally, profile, then decide how to optimize.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't there would be a small advantage to the explicit overload set (beyond the code looking simpler) in that, assuming `Foo`'s move constructor is `noexcept` while the copy constructor isn't, you could declare `NeedsCopyOfFoo(Foo&& foo) noexcept : m_myFoo{std::move(foo)} {}` and potentially benefit, performance-wise, in cases where your class is used contexts that provide the strong exception guarantee by using `std::move_if_noexcept`? The templated version could be made conditionally `noexcept` too, but at the cost of even more complicated code.

Comment: The templated version would be even more complicated of course, because `T` and `U` might be initializer lists, values implicitly convertable to `Foo`/`Bar`, or similar stuff that's likely to invoke non-`noexcept` constructors, casting operators, etc., even if `T`/`U` themselves are in fact r-value references and `Foo`/`Bar` provide `noexcept` move constructors. I'm assuming there is some way to determine if the expression `m_myFoo{std::forward<T>(foo)}` is `noexcept`, but it's way outside the scope of my C++ knowledge.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `noexcept` for the special member functions is `noexcept` by default unless a member/base is not.  Making `NeedsCopyOfFoo(Foo&& foo)` `noexcept` realy wont do anything.  It's `NeedsCopyOfFoo(NeedsCopyOfFoo&&)` that you want to be `noexcept`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Ah, right. Mixing up the names; this is a regular constructor, not a move constructor, it just happens to accept r-value references as arguments. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @ShadowRanger No worries.

Comment: @ShadowRanger `I'm assuming there is some way to determine if the expression [...] is noexcept, but it's way outside the scope of my C++ knowledge` Let's widen your knowledge: The expression `noecept(expr)` evaluates to true if it is noexcept, and false otherwise. So, in this case `noexcept(m_myFoo{std::forward<T>(foo)})` and to declare the function conditionally noexcept: `noexcept(noexcept(m_myFoo{std::forward<T>(foo)}))` (yes, it looks a bit silly). Also, to expand on what NathanOliver said, special member functions default to `noexcept` only if they are implicitly generated (or defaulted).

Answer (score 4):

I, for one, think you're doing everything correctly.

But, of course if copying your type is as fast as moving it<sup>1</sup>, then `std::move` becomes unnecessary, and such a type should be passed by value or by `const` reference depending on how cheap to copy it is.

<sub>1 — e.g. if it's a class that doesn't manage any heap memory or other resources</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a gross over-reaction to the newer C++ standards.

Leave these optimisations to the compiler; any decent one will eliminate superfluous value copies and from C++17 are required to do so in some instances.

Effective modern C++ is all about writing less code, not more code.

If you are ever in any doubt that your code is running slowly due to egregious amounts of value copies being taken, then profile it. Profiling is something you should undertake from time to time anyway.

Comment: Your claim of "Your code is a gross over-reaction to the newer C++ standards" must be supported by an explanation.  You didn't explain why std::move is not necessary.

Comment: @Wyck: 'cuz the compiler will do it.

Comment: Can you explain how you know that?

Comment: @Wyck: Check the assembly if you are in any doubt, profiling works too. And C++17 guarantees RVO with the odd exception (such as not applying if you return a function parameter).

Comment: @Bathsheba Are you saying `m_myFoo{foo}` will get optimized to `m_myFoo{std::move(foo)}` in the second case?  I've not seen a compiler that will do that and it doesn't [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35410742d65e561a)

Comment: @NathanOliver; No I'm saying don't bother with the second case until you see the need to. Something would have gone very wrong with the language if the first way was suboptimal.

Comment: @Bathsheba From everything I've seen the first constructor is suboptimal.  You can see my answer for why.  It's pretty close, and is what I would suggest you use unless profiling says otherwise, but it is not the most optimal solution.

Comment: @Bathsheba In most cases I have seen, compilers cannot optimize away a copy (aside from those elisions where the standard explicitly allows changing observable behavior, i.e. RVO and friends) if any dynamic memory allocation happens in the object. `new` usually has an observable side effect in the eyes of the compiler.

Comment: @Bathsheba `'cuz the compiler will do it` It did not do it (-O3): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbb27b8f6b06bff4

Comment: @NathanOliver `It's pretty close` Depends on `Foo`. If it for example contains a vector of million elements, then the difference is quite significant.

Comment: I think the problem with this answer is not that it isn't *broadly* correct; *broadly*, the compiler can and does eliminate all sorts of superfluous copies thanks to copy elision of one form or another, and explicitly using `std::move` in the cases where copy elision would have occurred is often a pessimization. The problem is that the OP's case is more specific, and the "receive `const` reference, use it to initialize member" case is one where copy elision is impossible; there will *always* be a copy, and saying "decent compilers eliminate superfluous copies" is misleading in context.